# Modulo and Negative Number in Math?

Tags: math, modulo

tonight I'm curious about modulo negative number in **Math**.

Regardless of programming languages, calculators while it [returns different values](https://torstencurdt.com/tech/posts/modulo-of-negative-numbers/) that depend on their own formula behind, what is the right answer if in the exam in junior school has these questions:

```
  -7 mod  2 = ?
   7 mod -2 = ?
  -7 mod -2 = ?
```

ps: I'm sorry if I'm too old to remember the answer of those "basis questions", and thank you for your kindness to give me a right answer!

ps2: to people who devote this question: trust me this question is really helpful, at least it could help you to understand why this block of code fail:

```js
function isEvenOrOdd(num) {
    return num % 2 === 1 ?'odd' : 'even';
}

isEvenOrOdd(5); // 'odd'
isEvenOrOdd(18); // 'even'
isEvenOrOdd(0); // 'even'
isEvenOrOdd(-7); // 'even'
```

Comment: It's safer to compare with zero: `return num % 2 !== 0 ?'odd' : 'even'; }`

Comment: @JohanC yeah Johan, I did it all the time until my intern does num % 2 !== 1, I realized that the module in programming can be negative :)! Then this question was asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In *mathematics,* the modulus must be >1 and the convention is that the modulo operation yields the smallest non-negative integer solution to `a+km=b`:

```
-7 mod  2 = 1
 7 mod -2     Illegal
-7 mod -2     Illegal
```

It is easy to extend the definition to include negative numbers (and 1 and -1):

```
-7 mod  2 = 1
 7 mod -2 = 1
-7 mod -2 = 1
-7 mod  3 = 2
```

But in *computing,* different languages use different conventions:

```
-7 mod  2 = {1, or -1, or undefined}
```

I suspect that your system says `-7 mod 2 = -1`, so that `isEvenOrOdd(-7);` yields 'even' (because -1 ≠ 1).

Comment: thanks you for your answer! This is what I'm curious! By the way, can you enlighten me up a little bit about the result of -7 mod 2: should it be -4 modulus 1 or -3 modulus 1?

Comment: @Kai: I don't understand your question. Are you asking me about `-7 mod 1`?

Comment: Oh I just want to ask the result of  -7 /2 = ?? . For positive number it is 7 / 2 = 3 modulus 1 ( 3 * 2 + 1  = 7 ).

Comment: @Kai: The modulus is the divisor, not the remainder. Mathematically, -7 mod 2 = 1 (because -7 = (-4)*2+1). Some computer systems do that, and some say that -7 mod 2 = -1 (because -7 = (-3)*2 + (-1)).

Answer (score 0):

To calculate x mod m where x is negative you need to keep adding m to x until it gets non-negative so -7 % 2 = -7 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 = 1.

To check if a number is odd or even always do it in absolute value like |x| mod m so you do not need to worry about the negative value with the modulo.

Comment: just double check, you mean that the result of -7 % 2 equal to `-4 modulus 1` or am I wrong?